# EXC_BAD_ACCESS Exception in objective-C in Insert into query

Tags: objective-c, xcode, insert-into

I am making an application in objective-C.

In this application i want to get data from database table.

In this table there are 225 column in which I want to insert data from objective c code.

When i insert 100 column it works fine but when i insert the 225 column value it hit an error:

```
Thread:1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS code:1 address:0xfffffffff.
```

The variable in which I specify the query is type of NSString .
Please tell me what is the problem and how to solve it.

```
tmpStr2=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into tblButterflyData(SeqNo,GeoLevelCode,GeoCode,FCMonth,CategoryCode,AFFig1,AFFig2,AFFig3,AFFig4,AFFig1Hdr,AFFig2Hdr,AFFig3Hdr,AFFig4Hdr,KLFig1,KLFig2,KLFig3,KLFig4,KLFig1Hdr,KLFig2Hdr,KLFig3Hdr,KLFig4Hdr,AFKLFig1,AFKLFig2,AFKLFig3,AFKLFig4,AFKLFig1Hdr,AFKLFig2Hdr,AFKLFig3Hdr,AFKLFig4Hdr,AFFig1YTE,AFFig2YTE,AFFig3YTE,AFFig4YTE,AFFig1HdrYTE,AFFig2HdrYTE,AFFig3HdrYTE,AFFig4HdrYTE,KLFig1YTE,KLFig2YTE,KLFig3YTE,KLFig4YTE,KLFig1HdrYTE,KLFig2HdrYTE,KLFig3HdrYTE,KLFig4HdrYTE,AFKLFig1YTE,AFKLFig2YTE,AFKLFig3YTE,AFKLFig4YTE,AFKLFig1HdrYTE,AFKLFig2HdrYTE,AFKLFig3HdrYTE,AFKLFig4HdrYTE,AFFig1YTD,AFFig2YTD,AFFig3YTD,AFFig4YTD,AFFig1HdrYTD,AFFig2HdrYTD,AFFig3HdrYTD,AFFig4HdrYTD,KLFig1YTD,KLFig2YTD,KLFig3YTD,KLFig4YTD,KLFig1HdrYTD,KLFig2HdrYTD,KLFig3HdrYTD,KLFig4HdrYTD,AFKLFig1YTD,AFKLFig2YTD,AFKLFig3YTD,AFKLFig4YTD,AFKLFig1HdrYTD,AFKLFig2HdrYTD,AFKLFig3HdrYTD,AFKLFig4HdrYTD,AddedOn,AddedBy,LastUpdatedOn,LastUpdatedBy,AFFig1AS8,AFFig2AS8,AFFig3AS8,AFFig4AS8,AFFig1HdrAS8,AFFig2HdrAS8,AFFig3HdrAS8,AFFig4HdrAS8,KLFig1AS8,KLFig2AS8,KLFig3AS8,KLFig4AS8,KLFig1HdrAS8,KLFig2HdrAS8,KLFig3HdrAS8,KLFig4HdrAS8,AFKLFig1AS8,AFKLFig2AS8,AFKLFig3AS8,AFKLFig4AS8,AFKLFig1HdrAS8,AFKLFig2HdrAS8,AFKLFig3HdrAS8,AFKLFig4HdrAS8,AFFig1SA8,AFFig2SA8,AFFig3SA8,AFFig4SA8,AFFig1HdrSA8,AFFig2HdrSA8,AFFig3HdrSA8,AFFig4HdrSA8,KLFig1SA8,KLFig2SA8,KLFig3SA8,KLFig4SA8,KLFig1HdrSA8,KLFig2HdrSA8,KLFig3HdrSA8,KLFig4HdrSA8,AFKLFig1SA8,AFKLFig2SA8,AFKLFig3SA8,AFKLFig4SA8,AFKLFig1HdrSA8,AFKLFig2HdrSA8,AFKLFig3HdrSA8,AFKLFig4HdrSA8,AFFig1AF8,AFFig2AF8,AFFig3AF8,AFFig4AF8,AFFig1HdrAF8,AFFig2HdrAF8,AFFig3HdrAF8,AFFig4HdrAF8,KLFig1AF8,KLFig2AF8,KLFig3AF8,KLFig4AF8,KLFig1HdrAF8,KLFig2HdrAF8,KLFig3HdrAF8,KLFig4HdrAF8,AFKLFig1AF8,AFKLFig2AF8,AFKLFig3AF8,AFKLFig4AF8,AFKLFig1HdrAF8,AFKLFig2HdrAF8,AFKLFig3HdrAF8,AFKLFig4HdrAF8,AFFig1CI8,AFFig2CI8,AFFig3CI8,AFFig4CI8,AFFig1HdrCI8,AFFig2HdrCI8,AFFig3HdrCI8,AFFig4HdrCI8,KLFig1CI8,KLFig2CI8,KLFig3CI8,KLFig4CI8,KLFig1HdrCI8,KLFig2HdrCI8,KLFig3HdrCI8,KLFig4HdrCI8,AFKLFig1CI8,AFKLFig2CI8,AFKLFig3CI8,AFKLFig4CI8,AFKLFig1HdrCI8,AFKLFig2HdrCI8,AFKLFig3HdrCI8,AFKLFig4HdrCI8,AFFig1ME8,AFFig2ME8,AFFig3ME8,AFFig4ME8,AFFig1HdrME8,AFFig2HdrME8,AFFig3HdrME8,AFFig4HdrME8,KLFig1ME8,KLFig2ME8,KLFig3ME8,KLFig4ME8,KLFig1HdrME8,KLFig2HdrME8,KLFig3HdrME8,KLFig4HdrME8,AFKLFig1ME8,AFKLFig2ME8,AFKLFig3ME8,AFKLFig4ME8,AFKLFig1HdrME8,AFKLFig2HdrME8,AFKLFig3HdrME8,AFKLFig4HdrME8,AFFig1FC8,AFFig2FC8,AFFig3FC8,AFFig4FC8,AFFig1HdrFC8,AFFig2HdrFC8,AFFig3HdrFC8,AFFig4HdrFC8,KLFig1FC8,KLFig2FC8,KLFig3FC8,KLFig4FC8,KLFig1HdrFC8,KLFig2HdrFC8,KLFig3HdrFC8,KLFig4HdrFC8,AFKLFig1FC8,AFKLFig2FC8,AFKFig3FC8,AFKLFig4FC8,AFKLFig1HdrFC8,AFKLFig2HdrFC8,AFKLFig3HdrFC8,AFKLFig4HdrFC8)values('%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@')",strSeqNo,strGeoLevelCode,strGeoCode,strFCMonth,strCategoryCode,strAFFig1,strAFFig2,strAFFig3,strAFFig4,strAFFig1Hdr,strAFFig2Hdr,strAFFig3Hdr,strAFFig4Hdr,strKLFig1,strKLFig2,strKLFig3,strKLFig4,strKLFig1Hdr,strKLFig2Hdr,strKLFig3Hdr,strKLFig4Hdr,strAFKLFig1,strAFKLFig2,strAFKLFig3,strAFKLFig4,strAFKLFig1Hdr,strAFKLFig2Hdr,strAFKLFig3Hdr,strAFKLFig4Hdr,strAFFig1YTE,strAFFig2YTE,strAFFig3YTE,strAFFig4YTE,strAFFig1HdrYTE,strAFFig2HdrYTE,strAFFig3HdrYTE,strAFFig4HdrYTE,strKLFig1YTE,strKLFig2YTE,strKLFig3YTE,strKLFig4YTE,strKLFig1HdrYTE,strKLFig2HdrYTE,strKLFig3HdrYTE,strKLFig4HdrYTE,strAFKLFig1YTE,strAFKLFig2YTE,strAFKLFig3YTE,strAFKLFig4YTE,strAFKLFig1HdrYTE,strAFKLFig2HdrYTE,strAFKLFig3HdrYTE,strAFKLFig4HdrYTE,strAFFig1YTD,strAFFig2YTD,strAFFig3YTD,strAFFig4YTD,strAFFig1HdrYTD,strAFFig2HdrYTD,strAFFig3HdrYTD,strAFFig4HdrYTD,strKLFig1YTD,strKLFig2YTD,strKLFig3YTD,strKLFig4YTD,strKLFig1HdrYTD,strKLFig2HdrYTD,strKLFig3HdrYTD,strKLFig4HdrYTD,strAFKLFig1YTD,strAFKLFig2YTD,strAFKLFig3YTD,strAFKLFig4YTD,strAFKLFig1HdrYTD,strAFKLFig2HdrYTD,strAFKLFig3HdrYTD,strAFKLFig4HdrYTD,strAddedOn,strAddedBy,strLastUpdatedOn,strLastUpdatedBy,strAFFig1AS8,strAFFig2AS8,strAFFig3AS8,strAFFig4AS8,strAFFig1HdrAS8,strAFFig2HdrAS8,strAFFig3HdrAS8,strAFFig4HdrAS8,strKLFig1AS8,strKLFig2AS8,strKLFig3AS8,strKLFig4AS8,strKLFig1HdrAS8,strKLFig2HdrAS8,strKLFig3HdrAS8,strKLFig4HdrAS8,strAFKLFig1AS8,strAFKLFig2AS8,strAFKLFig3AS8,strAFKLFig4AS8,strAFKLFig1HdrAS8,strAFKLFig2HdrAS8,strAFKLFig3HdrAS8,strAFKLFig4HdrAS8,strAFFig1SA8,strAFFig2SA8,strAFFig3SA8,strAFFig4SA8,strAFFig1HdrSA8,strAFFig2HdrSA8,strAFFig3HdrSA8,strAFFig4HdrSA8,strKLFig1SA8,strKLFig2SA8,strKLFig3SA8,strKLFig4SA8,strKLFig1HdrSA8,strKLFig2HdrSA8,strKLFig3HdrSA8,strKLFig4HdrSA8,strAFKLFig1SA8,strAFKLFig2SA8,strAFKLFig3SA8,strAFKLFig4SA8,strAFKLFig1HdrSA8,strAFKLFig2HdrSA8,strAFKLFig3HdrSA8,strAFKLFig4HdrSA8,strAFFig1AF8,strAFFig2AF8,strAFFig3AF8,strAFFig4AF8,strAFFig1HdrAF8,strAFFig2HdrAF8,strAFFig3HdrAF8,strAFFig4HdrAF8,strKLFig1AF8,strKLFig2AF8,strKLFig3AF8,strKLFig4AF8,strKLFig1HdrAF8,strKLFig2HdrAF8,strKLFig3HdrAF8,strKLFig4HdrAF8,strAFKLFig1AF8,strAFKLFig2AF8,strAFKLFig3AF8,strAFKLFig4AF8,strAFKLFig1HdrAF8,strAFKLFig2HdrAF8,strAFKLFig3HdrAF8,strAFKLFig4HdrAF8,strAFFig1CI8,strAFFig2CI8,strAFFig3CI8,strAFFig4CI8,strAFFig1HdrCI8,strAFFig2HdrCI8,strAFFig3HdrCI8,strAFFig4HdrCI8,strKLFig1CI8,strKLFig2CI8,strKLFig3CI8,strKLFig4CI8,strKLFig1HdrCI8,strKLFig2HdrCI8,strKLFig3HdrCI8,strKLFig4HdrCI8,strAFKLFig1CI8,strAFKLFig2CI8,strAFKLFig3CI8,strAFKLFig4CI8,strAFKLFig1HdrCI8,strAFKLFig2HdrCI8,strAFKLFig3HdrCI8,strAFKLFig4HdrCI8,strAFFig1ME8,strAFFig2ME8,strAFFig3ME8,strAFFig4ME8,strAFFig1HdrME8,strAFFig2HdrME8,strAFFig3HdrME8,strAFFig4HdrME8,strKLFig1ME8,strKLFig2ME8,strKLFig3ME8,strKLFig4ME8,strKLFig1HdrME8,strKLFig2HdrME8,strKLFig3HdrME8,strKLFig4HdrME8,strAFKLFig1ME8,strAFKLFig2ME8,strAFKLFig3ME8,strAFKLFig4ME8,strAFKLFig1HdrME8,strAFKLFig2HdrME8,strAFKLFig3HdrME8,strAFKLFig4HdrME8,strAFFig1FC8,strAFFig2FC8,strAFFig3FC8,strAFFig4FC8,strAFFig1HdrFC8,strAFFig2HdrFC8,strAFFig3HdrFC8,strAFFig4HdrFC8,strKLFig1FC8,strKLFig2FC8,strKLFig3FC8,strKLFig4FC8,strKLFig1HdrFC8,strKLFig2HdrFC8,strKLFig3HdrFC8,strKLFig4HdrFC8,strAFKLFig1FC8,strAFKLFig2FC8,strAFKLFig3FC8,strAFKLFig4FC8,strAFKLFig1HdrFC8,strAFKLFig2HdrFC8,strAFKLFig3HdrFC8,strAFKLFig4HdrFC8];
```

Comment: Do you think after rereading this that anyone can understand wht's going on?

Answer (score 0):

First, you would need to identify using the stack trace which library or piece of code is actually the culprit.  If the [NSString stringWithFormat:...] line of code is the issue, then you will want to check that all your arguments are valid, you may have one of them containing unexpected data.

For the sake of readability, you may want to break your query construction into smaller chucks, possibly using a helper method, such as:

```
- (void)forColumns:(NSMutableArray<NSString *> *)columns
         andValues:(NSMutableArray<NSString *> *)values 
         addColumn:(NSString *)column 
             value:(NSString *)value {
    [columns addObject:column];
    [values addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@'", value]];
}
```

Then to build your query:

```
NSMutableArray<NSString *> *columns = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableArray<NSString *> *values = [NSMutableArray new];

[self forColumns:columns andValues:values addColumn:@"SeqNo" value:strSeqNo];
[self forColumns:columns andValues:values addColumn:@"GeoLevelCode" value:strGeoLevelCode];

NSString *combinedColumns = [columns componentsJoinedbyString:@","];
NSString *combinedValues = [values componentsJoinedByString:@","];
tmpStr2=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into tblButterflyData(%@) values (%@)", combinedColumns, combinedValues];
```

Doing it this way makes your code a lot easier to read, avoids the issue of having a mismatched number of columns names and '%@',.... in your query string, helps you track which of your value may be invalid and makes your code a WHOLE lot easier to maintain.

There are various ways to optimize this to make it more efficient, but before that, you need to make it easy to maintain and bug free.  Good luck!